# Como definir um campo do tipo string como nullable no Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first, fluent-api

Tenho o campo `descrPapel` do tipo `string` e gostaria que esse campo fosse criado como `nullable`, ou seja, aceitasse `null` quando fosse fazer algum *insert/update* em registros desse tipo de entidade.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Modelo.Classes.Banco
{
    public class Papeis
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 idpapel { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(100)]
        public string nomePapel { get; set; }
        [Required,MaxLength(200)]
        public string descrPapel { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtInclusao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PapeisUsuario> PapeisUsuario  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Da forma que está o campo é criado para não aceitar valores `null` para esse campo `[descrPapel] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,`;

Veja como foi criado pelo Entity Framework:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Papeis](
    [idpapel] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nomePapel] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [descrPapel] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [dtInclusao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Papeis] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idpapel] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Precisava que este campo fosse criado como `[descrPapel] [nvarchar](200) NULL,`, existe alguma forma?

Comment: Usando fluent??

Comment: @jbueno Isso, ou DataAnnotations, algo que set como null no banco.

Comment: Eu não entendi o `[Required]` podendo ser nulo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando Fluent API é só adicionar o método `IsOptional` na declaração da propriedade.

Ex.: (no método `OnModelCreating`)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Papeis>()
            .Property(prop => prop.descrPapel)
            .IsOptional();
```

Pra aplicar como padrão para `strings`, é só fazer:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().IsOptional();
```

Comment: Sem querer abusar, sabe se tem como usar um padrão para as iniciais da variável? tipo onde começa com **descr** eu usar o .IsOptional();?

Comment: Tem como fazer com reflection, abre uma nova pergunta! Se eu não souber responder, tenho interesse numa resposta também

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, porém a opção "IsOptional()" não aparece para mim.
Houve alguma mudança?